User forced to add location so he can signup
I have an old code from an app and I don't know what I should comment in it so the user it is not forced anymore to add location so he can login... Here it's the image of the ui : 
What I should erase or change so it will not be a must when I touch create account to redirect to next page..
and here it is the code
class BusinessPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BusinessPageState createState() => _BusinessPageState();
}

class _BusinessPageState extends State<BusinessPage> {
  String? userId;
  var streat;
  var country;
  var locality;
  var postelCode;
  var category;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int selectedIndex1 = 0;
  int selectedIndex2 = 5;
  int selectedIndex3 = 8;

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  final elements1 = [
    "Servicii Agricultura",
    "Servicii Auto",
    "Servicii Beauty",
    "Servicii Constructii",
    "Servicii Curatenie",
    "Servicii pentru Animale",
    "Servicii Electrice",
    "Servicii Fitness",
    "Servicii Funerare",
    "Servicii Florale",
    "Servicii Instalatii",
    "Servicii IT",
    "Servicii Horeca",
    "Servicii Artistice",
    "Servicii Juridice",
    "Servicii Marketing si Printing",
    "Servicii Reparatii",
    "Servicii Transport",
    "Alte Servicii"
  ];

  final elements2 = [
    "12 AM",
    "1 AM",
    "2 AM",
    "3 Am",
    "4 AM",
    "5 AM",
    "6 AM",
    "7 AM",
    "8 AM",
    "9 AM",
    "10 AM",
    "11 AM",
    "12 PM",
    "1 PM",
    "2 PM",
    "3 PM",
    "4 PM",
    "5 PM",
    "6 PM",
    "7 PM",
    "8 PM",
    "9 PM",
    "10 PM",
    "11 PM",
    "12 PM",
  ];

  final elements3 = [
    "12 AM",
    "1 AM",
    "2 AM",
    "3 Am",
    "4 AM",
    "5 AM",
    "6 AM",
    "7 AM",
    "8 AM",
    "9 AM",
    "10 AM",
    "11 AM",
    "12 PM",
    "1 PM",
    "2 PM",
    "3 PM",
    "4 PM",
    "5 PM",
    "6 PM",
    "7 PM",
    "8 PM",
    "9 PM",
    "10 PM",
    "11 PM",
    "12 PM",
  ];

  List<Widget> _buildItems1() {
    return elements1
        .map((val) => MySelectionItem(
              title: val,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  List<Widget> _buildItems2() {
    return elements2
        .map((val) => MySelectionItem(
              title: val,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  List<Widget> _buildItems3() {
    return elements3
        .map((val) => MySelectionItem(
              title: val,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  LocationPermission permission = LocationPermission.denied;

  @override
  void initState() {
    userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    super.initState();
    getLocationPermission();
  }

  void getLocationPermission() async {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
              child: RichText(
                text: const TextSpan(
                  text: 'Tariffo',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontFamily: 'SignPainter',
                      fontSize: 60),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 40.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Location' : null,
                      controller: controller,
                      onTap: () async {
                        LocationPermission permission;
                        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
                        if (permission == LocationPermission.always ||
                            permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
                          Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                            context: context,
                            apiKey: Constants.googlePlaceKey,
                            mode: Mode.fullscreen, // Mode.fullscreen
                            // language: "",
                            components: [],
                            hint: "Enter Place",
                            offset: 0,
                            radius: 1000,
                            types: [],
                            region: "",
                            strictbounds: false,
                            onError: (value) {
                              logger.e("Error ${value.errorMessage}");
                            },
                          );
                          logger.e("Predication ${p != null}");
                          displayPrediction(p, context);
                        }
                      },
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Location',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Antra',
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  DirectSelect(
                      itemExtent: 50.0,
                      selectedIndex: selectedIndex1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                      child: MySelectionItem(
                        isForList: false,
                        title: elements1[selectedIndex1],
                      ),
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedIndex1 = index!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: _buildItems1()),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.93,
                    height: 60,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        TimeRange result = await showTimeRangePicker(
                          context: context,
                          onStartChange: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex2 = value.hour;
                            });
                          },
                          onEndChange: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex3 = value.hour;
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                          'Select work time (${selectedIndex2} AM - ${selectedIndex3} PM)'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        final translator = GoogleTranslator();
                        await translator
                            .translate(country, to: 'en')
                            .then((value) {
                          country = value.text;
                          print(country);
                        });
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                          'address': controller.text,
                          'country': country,
                          'disabled': false,
                        };
                        DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users')
                            .doc("$userId");

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .runTransaction((transaction) async {
                          transaction.update(reference, data);
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('dusers')
                            .doc(userId)
                            .set({});

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users/$userId/BusinessAccount')
                            .doc('detail')
                            .set({
                          'category': elements1[selectedIndex1],
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true)).catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                        });
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('${elements1[selectedIndex1]}')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'id': '$userId',
                          'categoryName': elements1[selectedIndex1],
                          'openTime': elements2[selectedIndex2],
                          'closeTime': elements2[selectedIndex3],
                          'address': controller.text,
                          'country': country,
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true)).catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Homepage SuperUser')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'user': '$userId',
                          'expired_on': DateTime.now()
                              .add(const Duration(days: 7))
                              .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                          'plan': 'free',
                          'notified': false,
                          'expired': false,
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Category SuperUser')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'user': '$userId',
                          'expired_on': DateTime.now()
                              .subtract(const Duration(days: 7))
                              .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                          'plan': 'free',
                          'notified': true,
                          'expired': true,
                        });

                        print(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 7)));

                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => const Homepage()));
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Create your account',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text('Start with your 7 days free promotion',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction? p, BuildContext context) async {
    if (p != null) {
      var placeId = p.placeId;

      var address = await FlGeocoder(Constants.googlePlaceKey)
          .findAddressesFromPlaceId(placeId!);
      controller.text = p.description ?? "";
      country = address.first.country?.longName;
    }
  }
}

class MySelectionItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool isForList;

  const MySelectionItem({Key? key, required this.title, this.isForList = true})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 80.0,
      child: isForList
          ? Padding(
              child: _buildItem(context),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            )
          : Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildItem(context),
                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  _buildItem(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }
}


Try to comment the TextFormField(). Then handle where the "controller.value" is used. You can just replace the "controller.value" to "".

ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String

check your variables like: streat, country, locality, postelCode, category. one of them is not initializing. and you try to use it somewhere. Try to give them a default value (example: var country = "India")  do this with all variables and try to run it once.

Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because
'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
country = address.first.country?.longName;

start by commenting the validator of the text field, and try to stop all firebase ops that uses the location.

Just assign a string value to country variable like : "country = "test";

Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because
'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
country = address.first.country?.longName;

same error when I write test
